# How to run an executable in iOS App?

Tags: ios, shell, command-line, command, nstask

I want to run an executable file in my **iOS** app. (or execute some command line commands)

I think this can be done with the help of NSTask, but that doesn't seem to be available in iOS (its available for mac OS X only).

So,

1. How can i run an executable from my app ? OR How can i execute shell commands from my app ?
2. How can i make use of NSTask in **iOS** ?
3. Are there any other libraries like NSTask which i can make use of ?
4. If none of the above is possible, please let me know a way around.

I want my app to be uploaded on the app store, so please don't answer anything related to jailbreaking.

Also,
Don't tell me apple would reject it, i want to take a chance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run an executable from your app due to the sandboxing. From the list 1-4 are not possible.

`NSTask` is not available because it would violate the sandboxing.

Comment: See answer. Apple has closed down code execution because it is a potential security violation avenue.

Comment: I can't even run a shell script ?

Comment: Shell scripts can not be run. You can run any code that is compiled into your app—only. That too would break sandboxing. I suspect that Apple has thought this out rather well. ;-)

Comment: Oh...
Then what's the run script that can be added in the build phase ?

Comment: The Run Script runs as part of the building the app only, it is not a part of the app.

Comment: Apple has everything else but though this out. Having worker threads is very important for software stability and to keep memory fragmentation low.