# How to run custom iOS native binary in iOS Cordova App

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I compiled a native binary from C code for iOS arm device. If looking it's info through `lipo` it shows this:

`$ lipo -info iOS_binary 
Architectures in the fat file: iOS_binary are: armv7 armv7s arm64`

It is a binary which only needs to run in the backend, and will serve API on port 7778 when running, which I want to use with the iOS App's front end.

For iOS App, I'm considering Ionic framework, using Cordova, meteor and nodejs.

I'm new to this iOS development, please help me on how can I run this native binary in my iOS App.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I added phonegap to it's tags. Wondering if it's possible to make a phonegap plugin which executes this native binary to make http service run in the background.

Comment: Is this still valid ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935939/how-to-run-an-executable-in-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question. But if I make native iOS app and using my own binary library, I just added in Xcode project destination of headers and include all binary libraries is project settings.

I am not sure how this works with Ionic and Cordova.

Comment: It's an executable binary file which only starts in terminal. Example: executing `./example_run_file` from terminal makes a HTTP API calls available on port 7778. Accessing http://127.0.0.1:7778/api/test/message="hello world" will give result in json output.